# Alternative to using (Event Receivers & Server-side object model) when working with Office 365 sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, client-object-model, event-receivers, ssom

I have being working with on-premise sharepoint 2013. and a lot of functionalities i have been doing were implemented inside Event Receivers when item added/updated.

Where inside Visual Studio 2012 Professional, i create the event receivers and using server-side object model SSOM i update certain fields, send API requests to external system , send emails, etc.

Now we are going to work with office 365 sharepoint, and as i know event receivers + serve-side object model are not available inside sharepoint online.

So let say i want to implement a scenario such as:- an item Priority will be set to "high" if the user who create the item  is within the "Company Manager" security group.

Now inside SharePoint 2013 on-premise, i would create an event receiver using VS 2012, and using server-side object model will allow me to access the item fields , security groups , and then updates the item Priority field.
so inside sharepoint online what will be the appraoch i need to follow? which mimic Event Receivers &  SSOM ??
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options for this type of event handling when developing for SharePoint Online: Remote Events Receivers and WebHooks.

Remote Event Receivers are similar to Server-Side Event Receivers but instead of the event triggering a call to code running on the SharePoint Server, it triggers a call to an external web service. In that web service you can use the Client Object Model to interact with SharePoint. See [Use remote event receivers in SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint) for more information.

The other option we have is Webhooks which are more of an industry standard way of handling events with a web service. You register your endpoint as a handler for an event and then SharePoint will send a message to your endpoint when an event occurs. See [Office Dev PnP Web Cast – Introducing SharePoint WebHooks](https://dev.office.com/blogs/introducing-sharepoint-webhooks) for more information.

Comment: now i am starting learning about apps mainly to write remote event receivers. but generally speaking should the remote event receiver which get called when list item are create, updated, delete be created as SP-hosted app(add-in) or provider-hosted app(add-in)? or both will work?

Comment: Remote event receivers are part of a web service that is hosted external to SharePoint. So, by definition, they are provider-hosted. If you add a remote event receiver to a SharePoint-hosted App, a new project gets added to your Visual Studio solution (this project contains the implementation of the remote event receiver) and your SharePoint-hosted App now becomes a hybrid app - part SharePoint-hosted and part provider-hosted.

Comment: so you mean i can have my remote event receiver as provider-hosted OR as hybrid ?? but can not have my remote event receiver  as SP-hosted only ??

Comment: That is correct. You cannot have just a SharePoint-hosted app that has a remote event receiver.

Comment: As i did not work on remote event receivers before, so what are the differences between having remote event receiver has provided-hosted or as hybrid solution?and does one appraoch provide features that the other can not?second point now seems remote event receivers are more complicated than just adding event receiver + server side code. i know remote event receiver are the only option for office365, but do we need to create them inside on-premise 2013 or 2016? as dealing with event receivers + server-side code is more straight forward and developers feel comfortable dealing with it.

Comment: I can't explain everything about remote event receivers in a comment. There are lots of resources to help you, a Google search for "sharepoint remote event receivers" should give you more than enough to get started.

Comment: at this stage i am just trying to understand if creating a remote event receiver as a provided-hosted app will give me better capabilities compared to creating it as a hybrid solution ?? so i can know from where to start my path to understand remote event receivers?thanks

Comment: No, there is no difference in functionality. The only differences are in how your Visual Studio project is structured and how you deploy the app.